# Accessing a url in a Flask view

Tags: python, api, flask

I am trying to access an external url https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=184&format=json in a Flask view

I get the error,

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

Is that my local server that flask is looking for this url on. And if so why? I am running flask locally.

The view, services.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import json
import urllib2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'Everything is running!'

@app.route('/stopid')
def stopid():
    dublin_bus_url = "https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=184&format=json"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(dublin_bus_url)
    json_response = json.load(response)
    routes = set()
    for result in json_response["results"]:
        routes.add(result["route"])

    return json.dumps(list(routes))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The index.html and script is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    d3.json("/stopid", function(error, routes) {
      routes.forEach(function(route) {
        console.log(route)
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Flask but this must not be the way to deal with an external link in a view.

The code above is adopted from this excellent tutorial for the Donorschoose api.

https://youtu.be/bzl4hCH2CdY

https://github.com/VidyaSource/starting-with-data

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the HTML file is not being served by `flask`:

You need to enable Cross origin resource sharing. You can do this by creating a response and setting it's header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`: that is everyone. Or you can set it to your own domain when deploying.

```
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

Also, you're calling  `d3.json("/stopid" ...` you need to change this to:

```
d3.json("http://localhost:5000/stopid" ...
```

Complete code:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import json
import urllib2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'Everything is running!'

@app.route('/stopid')
def stopid():
    dublin_bus_url = "https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=184&format=json"
    my_response = urllib2.urlopen(dublin_bus_url)
    json_response = json.load(my_response)
    routes = set()
    for result in json_response["results"]:
        routes.add(result["route"])

    resp = jsonify(list(routes))
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

If the HTML is being served by flask, there is no need to enable cross origin sharing.

```
@app.route('/d3')
def d3():
    return render_template('d3.html')
```

Call the link to this url using:

```
d3.json("{{ url_for('stopid') }}", ...
```

But this isn't exactly reliable, because you don't want to use the api using javascript when you can do it in flask itself.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering. I have a bit to do to get your suggestion to work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think it is correct to say that the html file is being served by Flask.

Comment: So are you doing `render_template('d3.html')` ?

Comment: @ofey Check my updated answer if you're serving the html using flask.

Comment: Your most recent answer works. Strange as what I was originally doing works in the tutorial but not when I try to apply it to this different API. Thanks for your help.